# How can I translate the Profile 2 field labels?

Tags: users, i18n-l10n

I can't find a way to translate the fields labels for the Profile 2 fields. I have activated the Profile 2 translation module, but I don't want to translate fields of the entity, I just want to show the labels translated in the user page and the user edit form.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** the following description describes the steps for Drupal 8, but they are similar for Drupal 7:

---

You need the [potx](https://www.drupal.org/project/potx) module to extract a translation template which you can translate. Unfortunately there isn't an official Drupal 8 release available, but you can use [this github fork](https://github.com/kgaut/drupal-potx/), which works fine for my needs.

Here is a short procedure to handle translations of my modules:

#### 1. extent your module with the [Interface Translation Properties](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21locale%21locale.api.php/group/interface_translation_properties/8.3.x) (only Drupal 8)

Example `my_module.info.yml`:

```
name: My Module
description: ''
type: module
core: 8.x

'interface translation project': my_module
'interface translation server pattern': modules/my_module/translations/%language.po
```

Now your module is available for the `locale` module and translation can be handled with `drush locale-check` resp. `drush locale-update`.

#### 2. create a subfolder for your translations

In the subfolder `./modules/my_module/translations` I put the generated template and the `*.po` files. Fore more information have a look at the [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1814954) on drupal.org.

#### 3. create your template

I'm using **drush** to create the template. The best way for me is the creation with

```
drush potx single --folder=modules/my_module/ --api=8
```

It generates a `general.pot` file at the root directory of your Drupal installation. I move it into the translation folder but it's not necessary.

#### 4. create your translation

To create a translation I'm using [Poedit](https://poedit.net/) as editor. You can create different language files from the `general.pot` template. The free version of Poedit is quiet useful for editing `*.po` files. Save your language files in the translation folder.

#### 5. import the translations

Run the following commands to import the translations:

```
drush locale-check && drush locale-update
```

And clear the cache:

```
drush cr
```

That's it ;)

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention it is a Drupal  7 installation.

Comment: A sorry but then the procedure is similar. Then you can use the official potx module.